# how to change background image for a selected text in a gallery in android?

Tags: android

I have a text gallery.I need to give a background image for each selected textview in the gallery when the text is clicked.Pls give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
    textview[position].setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

});

Comment: u r using this gallery for displaying text right? so you have to provide the object of that text there

Comment: but the textview [posiotion] is showing error.its telling the type of expression must be an array type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing on 2.1 or later, then you can can add `android:onClick="onTextViewClick"` to `TextView` in XML. Then in the activty class add:

```
public void onTextViewClick(View v ) {
    v.setBackgroundImage(image); // set background.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

better you set the background to a state list drawable
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

create  xml file in drawable folder, with content like

```
<?xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:sstrong texttate_selected**="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_backround"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_background"/>
</selector>
```

where **selected_backround** and **normal_background** are drawable resources